# Can't find VS 2019 Project Defaults in Property Page

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I tried to change my character set with the project defaults but when I access the property page on my project and I go the general section in the configuration properties, it doesn't show the project defaults. Do you know any way to fix it so that I can edit my character set?
[image: image of settings]

Comment: Your screen looks normal for a c++ application.  Character Set is in "Advanced"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have selected the wrong menu for character set. Its in the advanced settings of Visual Studio 2019

[image]